# How to limit the number of results of this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, limit

I have a table *questions*, with columns *question_id, question_title* and *question_topic(c or java)*. How do I write a query that returns all 'c' questions?

If however, the number of 'c' questions is less than say 5, I also include 'java' questions, so that the total number of results is at most 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from questions where question_topic = 'c'
union
select * from questions where question_topic in ("c","java") order by question_type limit 10;
```

the first select gives you all the C questions and the second gives you the first 10. When you union you don't get duplicates

Answer (score 0):

for your specific scenario this should suffice

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY question_topic LIMIT 10;
```

basically your sort in alphabetical order based on topic, and get the first 10 results.

Answer (score 0):

You could just order by question type. 'C' will come before 'java'. So this query should return what you want:

```
select * from questions where question_topic in ("c","java") order by question_type limit 10;
```

If there are 10 'C' questions, you will get them all. otherwise, the balance of 10 will be filled by java.

Comment: But I want all questions of type c. Only if that is less than 10, I want to add the required number of java questions to make the total at most 10.

Comment: Ah. My bad. I misunderstood. Let me chew on that if someone else doesn't beat me to it.